# How do I resize the html5 canvas size of say-cheese jquery plugin for webcam?

Tags: jquery, canvas, webcam

I just started to use a relatively simple jquery plugin for accessing my webcam
https://github.com/leemachin/say-cheese

I wanted to resize the canvas based on my DIV's width, while maintaining scale-ratio

The documentation doesn't say anything about this...

regards

Comment: try reading the source of the plugin, there is some numbers that might affect this.

Comment: 16:9 aspect ratio would be 100% width and 56.8% height. try setting the parent div to `height: auto` and the child div to `min-height:56.8%`. if this doesn't help, try googling about the video-js plugin. it seems like there was a tutorial somewhere about making video js responsive and maintaining aspect ratio. hope this helps.